# iOS cannot set UITextField text property in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` of 'people' for my iOS app. I have created an 'add' screen to add new people to my persistent store, which works perfectly.

This add view uses a form created with a `UITableView` and subclassed `UITableViewCell`s, with a `UITextField` and `UILabel`, which although works well, I am very new to iOS programming and feel that this may not be the most efficient way.

I am trying to re-use this add view to be my detail, add, and edit view, and I can successfully set a 'Person' entity as a property in the detail view. I have the following code in my `viewDidLoad` method, where the `adding` property is set in the `prepareForSegue` method in the previous ViewController :

```
if (self.adding)
{
    self.editing = YES;
    self.title   = @"Add Person";
}
else
{
    self.title = self.person.name;

    [self setDetail];
}
```

My problem is that when I try to pre-populate my detail view's fields (my `setDetail` method), I am unable to set my UITextField text with the name property from my person entity. Here's the code I'm using to retrieve the UITextField and set it's `text` property with:

`form` is the UITableView;

```
UITableViewCell *nameCell  = [form cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]];
UITextField     *nameField = (UITextField *)[nameCell viewWithTag:100];
nameField.text = self.person.name;
```

If I NSLog `nameCell` it returns `(null)`

I hope that's enough explanation. Any pointers would help a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting in viewDidLoad:, do it in your table view data source methods. i.e

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     // Deque the nameCell and prepare the cell if its not available.
     UITextField     *nameField = (UITextField *)[nameCell viewWithTag:100];
     nameField.text = self.person.name;
     return nameCell.
}
```

Comment: Something so simple, yet I completely overlooked it. Haha, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` may return nil because

> Return Value
>   An object representing a cell of the table or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.

Official Document: [cellForRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath%3a)